# Form submitting DropDownListFor with Required field

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist from a table called StampsCSEMonths_test. Im trying to make the dropdown required before submitting the form.
The problem it always submits the form no matter if I select or not.

What could be the issue?
View:

```
@model WINHRAdmin.Models.CTS_Stamps

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.stampscsemonths_id, ViewBag.StampsCSEMonths_test as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "", new { @class = "form-control  " })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.stampscsemonths_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    }
```

Model:

```
namespace WINHRAdmin.Models
{
    public class CommitmentToServiceModel
    {

    }

    public class CTS_Stamps
    {
        [Required]
        [Range(1,Int32.MaxValue,ErrorMessage ="MonthYerar is required")]
        public int? stampscsemonths_id { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CTS_Stamps()
{

  ViewData["StampsCSEMonths_test"] =

   new SelectList((from s in _IntranetEntities.StampsCSEMonths_test.OrderByDescending(x => x.stampscsemonths_id).ToList()
                   select new
                   {
                       stampscsemonths_id = s.stampscsemonths_id,
                       FullName = s.month + "/" + s.year
                   }),
       "stampscsemonths_id",
       "FullName",
       null);


    LoadEmployeer();
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]

public ActionResult CTS_Stamps(FormCollection collection)
{

    var testvar = collection["stampscsemonths_id"];//after submission it does get the value of ID

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Will adding ModelState.IsValid In you CTS_Stamps POST action be of any help?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would want to use a client-side library like jquery.validate to prevent form submission if it's invalid.  Here is a good article on the subject: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718004/ASP-NET-MVC-Client-Side-Validation.

The usual pattern for server-side MVC validation is almost what you're doing.  You put the [Required] attribute above your data model attribute.  That's good.  You have a @ValidationMessageFor element in your view.  Also good.

You forgot, however, to check if the model is valid in your controller.  Add a check for ModelState.IsValid before you process the results.  Something like this:

```js
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(collection); // assumes collection is the model
            }
```

If the user submits an invalid form, after the round-trip they will see a validation error message next to the missing field.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please provide more detail than "no this didnt work"  What did you try? What were the error messages?  What was the result?  Please help us help you.